# JSF Primefaces Ajax update

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

How can I update my datatable by ajax row select function?
What would it be the values that will be put on update parameter ? 
thanks for your help

Here is my code, there is a datatable and after I click one of the rows in datatable then it shows detail of that row in datatable below but there is a problem with update

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head></h:head>
    <h:body>
        <f:view>
            <h:form id="form">
                <p:dataTable id="users" var="user" value="#{userOS.osList}"
                    paginator="true" rows="10" rowKey="#{user.kisiid}"
                    selection="#{userOS.selectedOS}" selectionMode="single">
                    <f:facet name="header">  
                                            Kullanıcı detaylarını görmek için view butonuna tıklayınız
                                            </f:facet>
                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{userOS.onRowSelect}"
                        update=":form" oncomplete="userDialog" />

                    <p:column headerText="Student No" sortBy="ogrencino"
                        filterBy="ogrencino" id="ogrencino">
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.ogrencino}" />
                        <f:param name="kid" value="#{userOS.osList.rowIndex}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Name" sortBy="ad" filterBy="ad" id="ad">
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.ad}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Surname" sortBy="soyad" filterBy="soyad"
                        id="soyad">
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.soyad}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Faculty" sortBy="altbirim.ad"
                        filterBy="altbirim.ad" id="altbirim">
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.altbirim.ad}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Department" sortBy="bolum.ad"
                        filterBy="bolum.ad" id="bolum">
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.bolum.ad}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Status" sortBy="ogrencidurum.ad"
                        filterBy="ogrencidurum.ad" id="ogrencidurum">
                        <h:outputText value="#{user.ogrencidurum.ad}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <f:facet name="footer">
                    </f:facet>
                </p:dataTable>


                <p:tabView id="tabView">
                    <p:tab id="dialog" title="User Detail" widgetVar="userDialog">
                        <h:panelGrid id="panelgrid" columns="2" cellpadding="4">
                            <p:dataTable id="display" var="adres" value="#{userOS.adresList}">
                                <p:column headerText="Adres Tipi">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{adres.addressType}" id="adresturu"/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Adres">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{adres.address}" id="adres"/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="İl">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{adres.city}" id="sehir"/>
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="Ülke">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{adres.country}" id="ulke"/>
                                </p:column>
                            </p:dataTable>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:tab>
                    <p:tab id="tab2" title="Godfather Part II">

                    </p:tab>

                    <p:tab id="tab3" title="Godfather Part III">

                    </p:tab>
                </p:tabView>
            </h:form>
        </f:view>
    </h:body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are updating the entire `@form`, in which you are keeping both DataTables.
So why don't you update only the second DataTable when you select a row in First DataTable.
Since your second Datatable is in `p:tabView` so it will take ID as `tabView:display`.
So your `p:ajax` would be:

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" process="@this" listener="#{userOS.onRowSelect}"
             update=":form:tabView:display" oncomplete="userDialog" />
```

**OR**

You can move the Second Table in separate Table and update entire Form.
In my experience with `p:tabView` I don't keep `p:tabView` inside form.
Rather I'll keep form inside `p:tabView`.
See this Code:

```
<h:form id="form">
   <p:dataTable id="users" var="user" value="#{userOS.osList}" ...>

        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{userOS.onRowSelect}"
                        update=":tabView:form2" oncomplete="userDialog" />
         .....
         .....
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>

<p:tabView id="tabView">
   <p:tab id="dialog" title="User Detail" widgetVar="userDialog">
       <h:panelGrid id="panelgrid" columns="2" cellpadding="4">

          <h:form id="form2">
             <p:dataTable id="display" var="adres" value="#{userOS.adresList}">
                 ......
                 ......
              </p:dataTable>
           </h:form>

       </h:panelGrid>
    </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Comment: I'm taking this error after adding tabView:display
Ara 16, 2013 10:55:17 AM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/layout.xhtml]
javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with expression "tabView:display" referenced from "form:users".

Comment: I did what you wrote seperate forms but without any luck It only updated once, am I missing something in my code ?

Comment: No The problem is with TabView only.. finally I can say, **Try updating entire Tab View once**.