# Update datatable in primefaces with update attribute

Tags: jsf, primefaces, cdi

I have a form which contains data that are required, I used this code to do it:

```
<p: inputText id = "salary" value = "#{paymentBean.payment.salary}" required = "true" requiredMessage = "#{msg ['REQUIRED.SALARY']}" />
```

On the same page there is a datatable that contains the objects (Payment) that I add through the form. 
Once the object is added, I do a update to the datable to add the new object using this code:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{paymentBean.addNewPayment()}" value="#{msg['BUTTON.ADD_NEW_ACCOUNT']}" update=":msg :payment_table add_salary_form">
    <f:param name="employeeId" value="#{param['employeeId']}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

The problem I have is when the data are not entered and I click the button the update is done and the table appears empty!
However, the validation message appears properly as what there are mandatory data.

The datatable is

```
<p:dataTable id="payment_table" var="p" value="#{paymentBean.payments}" rows="15" paginator="true"
    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,20">

    <p:column headerText="#{msg['LABEL.SALARY']}">
        <h:outputText value="#{p.salary}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="#{msg['LABEL.DATE_PAYMENT']}">
        <h:outputText value="#{p.paymentDate}">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" />
        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="#{msg['LABEL.PAYMENT']}">
        <h:outputText value="#{p.paid == true ? 'Payé' : 'Non payé'}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

I use in CDI, for that my managed bean is like this: 
//IMPORT

```
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped; import javax.faces.context.FacesContext; import javax.inject.Inject; import javax.inject.Named;
```

//CLASS

```
@RequestScoped
```

@Named(value = "paymentBean")
public class PaymentBean implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 8709710274424668330L;

final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PaymentBean.class);

List<Payment> payments = new ArrayList<Payment>();

private Payment payment;

@Inject
private IPaymentService paymentService;

public PaymentBean() {
    payment = new Payment();
}


public void addNewPayment() {
    //CODE TO ADD PAYMENT
}

//GETTERS AND SETTERS
```

}

Comment: is msg your form id?

Comment: the msg is 
<p:messages id="msg" showDetail="false" closable="true" escape="true" autoUpdate="true" />

Comment: why you have this then? update=":msg :payment_table add_salary_form"

Comment: you have to invoke the update lke :form :element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSF Primefaces Ajax update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569950/jsf-primefaces-ajax-update)

Comment: i use update=":msg :payment_table add_salary_form" beacause i need to update juste 2 element in my page

Comment: in that case you need to do it like element1, element2

Comment: Yes i do it like you say, but the same problem

Comment: is it all inside the same form? are you using a form, right?

Comment: i supose it's correcte check this http://pastebin.com/kApbyuu7

Comment: what happen when you do this? update=":payment_table :add_salary_form">

Comment: the same ruslt EMPTY DATATABLE, I think it don't have relation with update's attribute because In primefaces, exactly in the datatable's component PAGINATOR when i change the number of rows for example from 5 to 10 the datatable became empty

Comment: the problem is a SCOPE i change the scope in @ViewScoped and it's working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try several things

1.- Ensure you have this datatable into a form tag.
2.- When you use `":"` in the update this mean is absolute and the correct command will be `update=":form-id:payment_table"`
3.- I recommend you only use **-** instead of **_** in the id because primefaces uses jquery and in some cases some command may fail for the search implementation of primefaces with jquery. The update looks like `update=":form-id:payment-table"`
4.- Create a wrapper and update the wrapper in your button the full solution to this will be:

```
<h:panelGrid id="grid-payment-table">
     <p:dataTable id="payment_table"
...
</h:panelGrid>
```

5.- Change your scope to @ViewScoped

Comment: shouldnt you have a space between :form-id and :payment-table?

Comment: Not is like when you find a element in DOM like FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent("form-home:hiddenOfile").getAttributes().get("value"). If your put a space you will  update your form and later update your data tabla named "payment-table"

Comment: I try the point number 1, but it's the same result ! 
there 's not in a relationship with CDI? and scope?

Comment: In primefaces, exactly in the datatable's component PAGINATOR when i change the number of rows for example from 5 to 10 the datatable became empty

Comment: I dont see the scope, is request you can change it to view minimal.

Comment: Yes i try it and it's WOORKING, thunk you MAN !!

Comment: Great, please dont forget rate.